# How to read Bin file in C preamble by preamble

Tags: c, bin

For example i have a bin file and many messages in this file i know msg starting preamble first two byte is 0x43 and 0x78 for example msg look like
CxdjjdjdjdjdjdeiCxejejejejdjdclCxejdjdd
How to read.Read Preamble by preamble
i want to read like this
1. Cxdjjdjdjdjdjdei
2. Cxejejejejdjdcl
3. Cxejdjdd

File is not a small file its a big file. i want to pick msg by msg and then read byte by byte then parse byte into the library function and check the result of this msg then read next and repeat all thing of every msg. i know msg not greater than 1400 bytes

Comment: If the file is small enough you can just load the whole thing into memory and look for the preambles. If it's bigger, you might need to load it into a large buffer and then process it one buffer at a time, but beware it's possible for the preamble to appear across the boundary between two of your block sizes.

Comment: File is not a small file its a big file. i want to pick msg by msg and then read byte by byte then parse byte into thhe library function and check the result of this msg then read next and repeat all thing of every msg. i know msg not greater than 1400 bytes.

Comment: no msg not a constant size some time 900 byte some time 350 for example. but not same

Comment: What is your real question, just implementation or an efficient way to solve?

Comment: _"ts a big file"_: how big?

Comment: just implementation how to get read msg by mag or preamble by like this. 1. Cxdjjdjdjdjdjdei 2. Cxejejejejdjdcl 3. Cxejdjdd... file size max is 500mb

Comment: @NomanNomi 500 mb was big 20 years ago, on modern computes it's just medium size.

Comment: @jabberwockky ok its medium how i can do this.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use a buffer larger than the maximum size of a message including the preamble. Since you said that no message will be greater than 1400 bytes, a 2048 buffer would be enough.

Pseudo code:

```
read a buffer
note no beginning of message
loop searching a preamble
    search (memchr) the first character of the preamble (0x43 or `'C'`)
    test is a full preamble is there - if not iterate previous search
    Ok, we have a preamble
    If a beginning of message was present
        we have a full message : process it
    If less that 1500 character remaining if the buffer
        copy the content of the buffer starting with the current preamble to the beginning of the buffer
        read enough bytes to have a full buffer
        if EOF: FINISHED
    Note the beginning of the message
end loop
```

As the messages are rather short, I would use buffered read (`fread`) to take advantage of the standard library buffering

Basis for C implementation:

```
const char preamble[] = {0x43, 0x78};
char buffer[2048];
size_t sz = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fd);
char *msg_start = NULL;        // no start of message
char *search_start = buffer;
size_t search_size = sz;
for(;;) {
    char *end = memchr(search_start, preamble[0], search_sz);
    if (end == NULL) {
        end = buffer + sz;
    }
    if ((end < buffer + sz - sizeof(preamble)) && memcmp(end, preamble, sizeof(preamble)) != 0) {
        size_t delta = end - search_start + 1;
        search_sz -= delta;
        search_start += delta;
        if (search_sz > sizeof(preamble)) continue;
        end = buffer + sz;
    }
    if (msg_start != NULL) {
        // process the message between  msg_start and end
    }
    if (end == buffer + sz) break;
    for (char *dest = buffer, char *src = end; src < end; src++, end++) *dest = *src;
    size_t delta =fread(buffer + sz, 1, sizeof(buffer) + sz, fd);
    if (delta == 0) break;
    sz += delta
    search_start = msg_start = buffer + sizeof(preamble);
}
```

BEWARE: untested and may content typos or incorrect code...